# Listings package: including punctuation in "emph" list

Tags: listings

I'm typesetting some examples of a system which has this sort of look:

```
In:  2+2
Out: 4
```

and I'd like to emphasis the "In:" and "Out": This works:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,emph={In,Out},emphstyle=\bfseries]
  In:  2+2
  Out: 4
\end{lstlisting}
```

but this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,emph={In:,Out:},emphstyle=\bfseries]
  In:  2+2
  Out: 4
\end{lstlisting}
```

where I want to include the colons in the emphasis, doesn't.  I've experimented with including `alsoletter={:}` in the options, to no effect.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Note, I am in fact using listings as part of a new environment defined with the `tcolorbox` package.  So:

```
\newenvironment{pyth}{%
   \tcblisting{listing only,colback=vlgray,colframe=vlgray,enhanced,
    overlay={\node[draw,fill=black,xshift=-10pt,yshift=4pt,left,text=white,
         anchor=east,font=\footnotesize\bfseries] 
         at (frame.south east) {Python};},%
    listing options={alsoletter={:},emph={In:,Out:},emphstyle=\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,breaklines=true,language=Python},}}
{\endtcblisting}
```

and then in my text:

```
\begin{pyth}
In:  2+2
Out: 4
\end{pyth}
```

In this particular environment `alsoletter` appears to have no effect.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

`alsoletter={:}` does work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{beramono}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,alsoletter={:},emph={In:,Out:},emphstyle=\bfseries]
  In:  2+2
  Out: 4
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update after the question edit:

Specify the language first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\colorlet{vlgray}{gray}% just for the example, since the original definition was not included

\newenvironment{pyth}
  {%
    \tcblisting{
      listing only,
      colback=vlgray,
      colframe=vlgray,
      enhanced,
      overlay={
        \node[
          draw,
          fill=black,
          xshift=-10pt,
          yshift=4pt,
          left,
          text=white,
          anchor=east,
          font=\footnotesize\bfseries
          ] 
           at (frame.south east) {Python};
       },%
      listing options={
        language=Python,
        alsoletter={:},
        emph={In:,Out:},
        emphstyle=\bfseries,
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
        breaklines=true,
      },
    }
  }
  {\endtcblisting}

\begin{document}

\begin{pyth}
In:  2+2
Out: 4
\end{pyth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the `beramono` package in my example just to have a mono-spaced boldfaced font.  I used `\colorlet{vlgray}{gray}` for the example, since the original definition was not included in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more info to my original post which may explain a bit better why I'm not getting the output I want.

Comment: @Alasdair please see my updated answer showing a possible solution using your settings.

Comment: Thank you!  Putting the language first works perfectly.  Thank you again for your time and trouble!

Comment: @Alasdair Be aware that making `:` a "letter" has consequences. For instance, if you've defined `for` to be a keyword, then `listings` won't highlight it in `for:`.